# Cakephp validations not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Validations are working but form is not getting submitted and data is not inserted:

addgroup.ctp:

```
echo $form->create('Group', array('url' => array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' =>'addgroup'), 'onSubmit' => 'return Validate()'));

echo $form->input('name',array('label' => false));

 <input type="submit"  value="Submit"/>

 <input type="button" value="Cancel"/>
```

Group Model:

```
var $validate = array(

    'name' => array(    
        'isRequired' => array(
            'rule' => 'required',
            'message' => 'Enter group name.'
        ),      
        'isUnique' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',               
            'message' => 'This group name has already been taken.'
        ),
    ),
);
```

in controller:

```
$this->Group->save($this->data,array('validate' => true)
```

If I make any empty entry or duplicate entry it gives errormessge, 
but if I make valid entries then also form gives error-message, 
What m I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to close the form `$this->Form->end('Submit');` and the save function: `$this->Group->save($this->data);` It will validate when it saves.